# UILabel Dynamic Width calculation Multiple Lines

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have `UILabel` where i have 2 lines of text. I used the below code to calculate the dynamic **width** and **height**

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[aLabel text] sizeWithFont:aLabel.font
                                         constrainedToSize:aLabel.frame.size
                                             lineBreakMode:aLabel.lineBreakMode];

 CGRect rect =  [aLabel frame];
    rect.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
    [aLabel setFrame:rect];
```

Now if there is multiple lines in the `UILabel` how can i detect the width. See the image for more clearence. [image: End Co-ordinates of UILabel text]

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the X,Y of the last character on the second line? Because you already know the width as you've calculated it

Comment: @Flexicoder: Yes absolutely..!!

Comment: Can I ask why? If you want to insert some variable text in there, why can't you use `NSString stringWithFormat`?

Comment: @Flexicoder : I just need to add a actionable text there, so i need to add a UIButton at the end of UILabel text.

Comment: How would you know if there was enough space for the button. I would suggest that you keep them separate

Comment: I will add the UIButton as a subview for the self.!

Answer (score 0):

set property for Label

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;

CGFloat labelHeight=  [self heightOfLabelWithIngredientLine:pixers.name];

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,labelHeight)];

- (CGFloat)heightOfLabelWithIngredientLine:(NSString *)stringLabel
{

    CGRect frame;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    frame = [stringLabel boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(20.0f, 999.0f) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
    return frame.size.height;
}
```

Customize your label properties in

```
- (CGFloat)heightOfLabelWithIngredientLine:(NSString *)stringLabel
```

method.